# TexMaker doesn't generate a pdf file

Tags: pdftex, pdf, texmaker, ubuntu

I'm new to LaTeX and wanted to learn it via TexMaker but for some reason TexMaker doesn't generate a pdf file.

It generates a dvi file just fine but refuses to generate a pdf file (which makes it so that I can't use the in app previewer).

I'm running Ubuntu 20.04 with pdfTex (ironically) and haven't changed TeXMakers standard settings

Log output in case that helps identify my problem...

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.20 (TeX Live 2019/Debian) (preloaded format=latex 2020.11.30)  11 FEB 2021 13:35
entering extended mode
 restricted \write18 enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**lab_assignment_1.tex
(./lab_assignment_1.TeX
LaTeX2e <2020-02-02> patch level 2
L3 programming layer <2020-02-14>
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2019/12/20 v1.4l Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo
File: size10.clo 2019/12/20 v1.4l Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count167
\c@section=\count168
\c@subsection=\count169
\c@subsubsection=\count170
\c@paragraph=\count171
\c@subparagraph=\count172
\c@figure=\count173
\c@table=\count174
\abovecaptionskip=\skip47
\belowcaptionskip=\skip48
\bibindent=\dimen134
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-dvips.def
File: l3backend-dvips.def 2020-02-03 L3 backend support: dvips
\l__pdf_internal_box=\box45
\g__pdf_backend_object_int=\count175
\l__pdf_backend_content_box=\box46
\l__pdf_backend_model_box=\box47
\g__pdf_backend_annotation_int=\count176
\g__pdf_backend_link_int=\count177
\g__pdf_backend_link_sf_int=\count178
)
(build/lab_assignment_1.aux)
\openout1 = `lab_assignment_1.aux'.

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for TS1/cmr/m/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
 [1

] (build/lab_assignment_1.aux) ) 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 366 strings out of 483141
 6383 string characters out of 5965176
 231749 words of memory out of 5000000
 15471 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 532338 words of font info for 24 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 36 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 25i,4n,19p,146b,97s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s

Output written on build/lab_assignment_1.dvi (1 page, 252 bytes).
```

Comment: use `pdflatex` as compiler

Comment: @Mafsi in texmaker? or do you mean that I should (via terminal or whereever) compile my file with pdflatex

Comment: In TexMaker if you use it. Choose PdFLatex or go to `Options>>ConfigureTexMaker>>QuickBuild>>PdfLatex+ViewPdf  then press F1`